# Find a path that minimize the difference of sum in upper and lower half in matrix

Tags: algorithm

Given a 2 dimensional array A[n][n] with positive integers. How can I find a path from (1, 1) to (n, n) such that the sum of entries strictly above the path and strictly below the path has the smallest difference (taking absolute value)? The path can only go from (1, 1) to (n, n) moving to right or bottom (but not top or left). Here, (1, 1) denotes the top-left corner and (n, n) denotes the bottom right corner. I'd want to see if a polynomial time solution exists, if not, can we do better than the brute force algorithm using O(2^(2n)*n) time?

I have tried some dp idea like dp[i][j] stores the optimal solution for A[1..i][1..j] but it is not the case that dp[i+1][j] has to use the same path for dp[i][j]. I think I need to do some case handling but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Hmm. If the integers are small, we can do dynamic programming where state consists of position (coordinates part) and balance of upper minus lower (knapsack part).

Comment: @Gassa Yes I get what you mean, do you think that there will be an actual polynomial time solution? Given the similarity of it to the subset sum problem, maybe only pseudo-polynomial solution exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is at least as hard as [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Consider the following variation of the knapsack problem: given weights W1, W2, ..., Wn, divide them between two persons, so that the difference in total weights is as small as possible. Here, one person corresponds to taking an item into knapsack, and the other person to leaving it out, and the goal is to get knapsack weight closest to sumW / 2.

Now, in this problem, put the weights W1, W2, ..., Wn on the main diagonal of our n-times-n matrix, and make all other elements zeroes. When we draw a path, we can decide for each element independently whether it will be above or below the line we draw. So, if we solve our matrix problem, that will give a solution to the knapsack problem as well.

Comment: This is right, though if the related knapsack can be solved in O(f(n)) for input size n, this analysis shows the OPs problem is at least O(f(n)) relative to an input size of n^2 (the matrix).

Comment: @Dave Hmm, right. I was more concerned with NP-completeness than the exact powers in polynomials.

Comment: *"When we draw a path, we can decide for each element independently whether it will be above or below the line we draw."* - I don't think so. For example, W1 and Wn are neither above nor below the path (they're **on** the path), and for two consecutive ones, you can't have one below and the other above the path.

Comment: Also, by alternating between going right and down, the whole diagonal is on the path, so the resulting difference is trivially zero and I don't think you can use that for the knapsack answer. (And nitpick, probably avoidable: the matrix entries shall be "positive integers", which your zeros aren't.)

Comment: I think you can make the idea work with a (n+1)² matrix instead, putting 1 on the diagonal, each weight both directly above and directly below the diagonal, and "infinity" (an integer larger than all weights) everywhere else. Then the optimal path will indeed choose for each weight individually whether to put it below or above the diagonal.

Comment: @KellyBundy Sure, if the path occupies cells and not borders, and so there's a third state for each cell, that complicates constructing the example. But it would be unlikely that such modification puts the problem in class P instead of NP. So I went with the cleaner version.

Comment: @KellyBundy I think the grid can be modified such that the weights are spaced out by 1 cell on the main diagonal. That would circumvent the "on the path" problem. For the positivity problem, we can scale the weights by a large multiplicative factor and set all empty cells to be very small, say 1

Comment: @TYeung *"spaced out by 1 cell on the main diagonal"*. Then the optimal path will still step onto the weights. But you can do what I already described.